# Patterns for fetching data inside a loop in the view?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's an example of a 'component' that I have.
Is this example, the rails cache is hit once every loop. Is there a way to avoid this?

- It is only used in my mobile views. Which means I fetching the data in the controller will fetch unnecessary data for the desktop views.
- Is it possible to avoid doing `show_ids = current_user.get_show_ids` in the view, outside the loop?

View:

```
@shows.each do |show|
  if logged_in?
    if current_user.is_following(show) ### Hitting the cache (!)
      #remove button
    else
      #add button
    end
  else
    #something else
  end
end
```

User model:

```
def is_following(show)
  get_show_ids.include?(show.id)
end

def get_show_ids
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "all_shows_ids", "v3"]) do
    Following.where("user_id = ?", id).pluck(:show_id)
  end
end
```

I've tried doing `@ids ||= get_show_ids.include?(show.id)` with the same result.

Comment: It may help if you show the relevant controller action and the relevant parts of the other two models involved. Also you can say something about the cache you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the models `Show` and `User` connected by a `Following` model for the n:m relation.

When you retrieve the shows, you can left join the Followings with a `user_id` of `current-user`. The result set will have the fields for Following set if there is such a following, and not if the user is not following.

Note you need to `select` the fields from `Following` model explicitly, otherwise the join will only return fields from the `Show` model

Comment: My first bullet `It is only used in my mobile views. Which means I fetching the data in the controller will fetch unnecessary data for the desktop views.`. Also, the `is_following` part is unnecessary for logged out users viewing the same page.